# In Rails, why would saving a new record return nil, and nothing gets saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I initialize an AdUnit object `au` with

au = AdUnit.new( cp )

where `cp` is equal to:

`{:name=>"second56", :description=>nil, :target_window=>"BLANK", :explicitly_targeted=>false, :ad_unit_sizes_attributes=>[{:height=>90, :width=>728, :is_aspect_ratio=>false, :environment_type=>"BROWSER"}], :dfp_id=>"22319511", :parent_id_dfp=>"22261791"}`

and the resulting object `au` is

`#<AdUnit id: nil, dfp_id: "22319511", parent_id_dfp: "22261791", parent_id_bulk: nil, name: "second56", description: nil, target_window: "BLANK", explicitly_targeted: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

At this point, `au.valid?` and `au.new_record?` both return `true`.

If I do `au.save` (or `au.save!` for that matter) the result is `nil` and nothing is saved to the database. but if I do

```
aud = au.dup
aud.save
```

the result is `true` and the record is saved.

I can save my object with the duplicate workaround, but this looks really weird to me. can anybody give any ideas as to why is this happening? Below the SQL fragments from the 2 save statements from Rails console.

Thanks in advance all Rails gurus.

Returning `nil` and not saving:

`SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "ad_units" ("created_at", "description", "dfp_id", "explicitly_targeted", "name", "parent_id_bulk", "parent_id_dfp", "target_window", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jan 2012 17:28:37 UTC +00:00], ["description", nil], ["dfp_id", "22400631"], ["explicitly_targeted", false], ["name", "zapiFirstLevel366"], ["parent_id_bulk", nil], ["parent_id_dfp", "1166751"], ["target_window", "BLANK"], ["updated_at", Wed, 04 Jan 2012 17:28:37 UTC +00:00]]
 => nil`

Returning `true` and saving:

`SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "ad_units" ("created_at", "description", "dfp_id", "explicitly_targeted", "name", "parent_id_bulk", "parent_id_dfp", "target_window", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jan 2012 17:29:58 UTC +00:00], ["description", nil], ["dfp_id", "22400631"], ["explicitly_targeted", false], ["name", "zapiFirstLevel366"], ["parent_id_bulk", nil], ["parent_id_dfp", "1166751"], ["target_window", "BLANK"], ["updated_at", Wed, 04 Jan 2012 17:29:58 UTC +00:00]]
 => true`

Comment: What does `au.errors.full_messages` give you?

Comment: When you use `save!` it should raise an exception if there is a problem when saving.

Comment: `au.valid?` returns true just before saving. and `au.save` still doesn't save anything, and return `nil` (not `true`, nor `false`). That's what's weird from my pov.

Answer (score 4):

OK, this was caused by the usage of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` when AdUnit has a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with AdUnitSize. So I got to learn that these 2 do not work together nicely.

The only thing is, it might be good to have a warning somewhere, instead of having to find out about it from `.save` returning nil on a `valid? = true` object instead of true or false.

Comment: OK, going deeper I have seen that this was caused by a `before_save` callback returning `false`, which causes the associated action (in this case `save` to cancel as per Rails specification. Hard way to learn!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I guess you can accept your own answer. Just edit your answer and add description of the comment above into it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `save!` raises an exception if the record is invalid. It doesn't return anything.

If you need a return value use only `save`.

Basically if `save!` didn't raise, the record is saved successfuly. If you don't see it, then you're probably loading it wrong.

Comment: the problem is that I am tracking the execution line by line in debug (and also replicating itin the console) and neither save nor save! end up NOT CREATING any record in the DB. the (`save` or `save!`) part of the discussion is trivial. `save` should return `true` or `false`, not `nil`. right?

Comment: OK, going deeper I have seen that this was caused by a `before_save` callback returning `false`, which causes the associated action (in this case `save` to cancel as per Rails specification. Hard way to learn!