# Attributes of object being saved as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, save

I have a model called Performers that has several columns (:name, :bio, :email), of which only name and email are validated. When I go into the console and type:

```
p = Performer.new(name: "example", email: "example@example.com")
p.save!
```

The object gets saved to the database, but all column values are nil. No errors are reported in the console. This is preventing one of the major components of my app from working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some `attr_accessor`'s in your model (than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660662/2483313) might be of interest to you)? Please post your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by removing an unnecessary attr_accessor in my embed.rb file. Turns out if you try to save to an attribute that has a redundant attr_accessor it just makes nil values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Performer` model doesn't have a validation for testing purposes.

also `:name => 'SO'` OR `name: 'SO'`

```
p = Performer.new(:name => "example", :email => "example@example.com")
#OR
p = Performer.new(name: "example", email: "example@example.com")
p.save!
```

Comment: removing the validations didn't help. Also the :name = was a typo. It's still creating an object with all nil attributes.

Comment: @CharlosDesbiens can u post yr `schema.rb` file there `Performer` one and Model too. Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731232/in-rails-why-would-saving-a-new-record-return-nil-and-nothing-gets-saved